# Bitbucket pipeline reactjs build error

Tags: git, reactjs, build, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I built web app using react.js, and I want to make build and deploy on the server using FTP on every commit. For that purpose, I configure bitbucket pipeline, but I get an error on build react app.

I tested my local machine by running "npm run build" command and it run successfully without any error, but on pipeline, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-app@0.1.0 build: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2018-05-16T13_18_01_726Z-debug.log
```

Here is bitbucket-pipeline configuration:

image: node:8.11.1-slim

```
pipelines:
default:
- step:
script:
- echo "This script runs only on staging branch"
branches:
staging:
- step:
caches:
- node
script: 
- npm install
- node --version
- npm --version
- npm run build
- apt-get update
- apt-get -qq install git-ftp
- git ftp init --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD -v $FTP_HOST
```

I checked node and npm version are same as I using on my local machine.

Comment: Is the user executing the pipeline the same? With the same environment variables? The same .npmrc?

Comment: @VonC yes I execute same pipeline and  environment vars

Comment: So the nprmc used is the same? Can you check by adding a first step in the pipeline with sh(`id -a; echo ${HOME}`)

Comment: @VonC I dont have any npmrc file, what's it and should i add it ?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc: I was wondering if that could differ between your environment and Jenkins'

Comment: @VonC I checked in window, and linux working fine, except on pipeline

Comment: Hence my additional step in that pipeline, to try to know more

Comment: @VonC I have no idea, how to make, please tell me what to write in file?

Comment: I am away (and on my phone at the moment), I will check that out my I go back

Comment: I have looked into it: if you have made it work on your main account (as opposed to Jenkins) and your main account does not have a `~/.npmrc`, then `npmrc` file is *not* an issue here.

Comment: Have the exact same problem. Would love an answer. Build has been working fine for the past 8 months. As soon as I try on pipelines it fails with a useless error message. Can't view the logs either.

Comment: @Matt replace `npm run build` with `CI= npm run build` or `CI=false npm run build`

Answer (score 3):

Replace the command `npm run build` to `CI=false npm run build`

this will resolve your problem